# My code and sometimes it says terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc. and then sometimes it doesnt

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why my code works only half of the time and it seems completely random when it works this is my code for a hash simulator and when I put "bru" it puts out what I want it to put but if I want to put bruh it sometimes outputs nothing but it also sometimes puts this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc

I have no idea what is wrong with my code and it doesn't tell me because it doesn't count as an error.

p.s. I am 4 days old with c++ please be specific

Here is the code. :)

```
   string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
   string lor[] = {"a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6", "g7", "h8", "i9","j0","k10","l11","m12","n13","o14","p15","q16","r17","s18","t19","u20","v21","w22","x23","y24","z25"};
   string password;
   string passhash[10] = {"","","","","","","","","",""};
   cout << "your password cant be more then 10 characters long!" << endl;
   cout << "password:";
   cin >> password;
   bool white = true;
   int justno = password.length();
   justno++;
   int just = -1;
   int justtwo = 0;
   if (password.length() >= 10){
       cout << "Password too long!" << endl;
   }
   while (white){
       just++;
       if (password[justtwo] == letters[just]){
           passhash[justtwo] = lor[just];
           justno--;
           justtwo++;
           cout << justno << endl;
           if (justno <= 0){
               cout << "your hashed password: " << passhash[0] << passhash[1] << passhash[2] << passhash[3] << passhash[4] << passhash[5] << passhash[6] << passhash[7] << passhash[8] << passhash[9] << endl;
               white = false;
           }
       }
   }
   cout << "lol";
   return 0;
```

Comment: What input causes it to crash?

Comment: like I said it does not count as an error so it doesn't tell me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (password[justtwo] == letters[just]){
```

There's absolutely nothing in the shown code that will enforce that, over here, `just` will always be less than `letters.size()`. `just` keeps getting incremented, without any apparent upper bound. Only some other tangentially related condition will stop this loop.

Therefore, at some point this expression become undefined behavior, and the shown code may or may not crash at this point.

P.S. The same thing appears to be true here, as well:

```
passhash[justtwo] = lor[just];
```

When accessing containers, of which `std::string`s are just a special kind, it is your responsibility to ensure that array indexes are valid, and within bounds.

P.P.S. The same thing is likely true for `justtwo` accesses as well, except that the logic is unclear, on that part. But if one enters a password that starts with a period, of example, this `if` condition will be false, so the loop will begin again, incrementing `just`. Still, `if` will be false and you are guaranteed undefined behavior, because the `letters` does not, obviously, contain a period, so it's guaranteed to run off the end of that array, and hillarity ensues. That much is pretty clear.

Comment: so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: One way to fix it is to not overrun the size of the vector or string.

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new how do you do this.

Comment: Of course there's a way to fix this: never access nonexistent values in an array, or nonexistent characters in a string. That's it. Out-of-bounds access is a result if either flawed logic of whatever you're trying to do here, or a flawed implementation of correct logic. Your first step is to figure out which one it is, then you can go from there. Start by writing down, step by step, the logical process you are attempting to implement. Then compare it with the code, and see if the code correctly implements the intended logical process, or not. If yes, the logic is flawed, if no, the code is.